# How to change MAC Address on windows 10 without third party software?

Tags: windows, windows-10, mac-address

I have a Surface Pro 7 Model 1866 i5 and was wondering how I could change the MAC Address. I can view the MAC Address using the `getmac` and `ipconfig /all` commands in powershell and cmd to view my MAC but couldn't use my traditional methods to change it. For example, my network driver (an Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160 MHz) has neither a "Network Address" nor a "Locally Administered Address" tab on its device manager properties page resulting in me not being able to tamper with the physical address of the adapter in devmgt, network properties (in control panel), and in the advanced properties and configurations of my network adapter in adapter settings in control panel. Also, while using the 
`Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "*" -RegistryKeyword "*" -IncludeHidden`
powershell command, neither of them (Network or Locally Administered Address) options appeared. It just showed:

```
----                      -----------                    ------------                   --------------- -------------
Wi-Fi                     Sleep on WoWLAN Disconnect     Disabled                       *DeviceSleep... {0}
Wi-Fi                     Packet Coalescing              Enabled                        *PacketCoale... {1}
Wi-Fi                     ARP offload for WoWLAN         Enabled                        *PMARPOffload   {1}
Wi-Fi                     NS offload for WoWLAN          Enabled                        *PMNSOffload    {1}
Wi-Fi                     GTK rekeying for WoWLAN        Enabled                        *PMWiFiRekey... {1}
Wi-Fi                     Wake on Magic Packet           Enabled                        *WakeOnMagic... {1}
Wi-Fi                     Wake on Pattern Match          Enabled                        *WakeOnPattern  {1}
Wi-Fi                     Global BG Scan blocking        Never                          BgScanGlobal... {0}
Wi-Fi                     Channel Width for 2.4GHz       Auto                           ChannelWidth24  {1}
Wi-Fi                     Channel Width for 5GHz         Auto                           ChannelWidth52  {1}
Wi-Fi                     Mixed Mode Protection          RTS/CTS Enabled                CtsToItself     {0}
Wi-Fi                     Fat Channel Intolerant         Disabled                       FatChannelIn... {0}
Wi-Fi                     Transmit Power                 5. Highest                     IbssTxPower     {100}
Wi-Fi                     802.11n/ac/ax Wireless Mode    4. 802.11ax                    IEEE11nMode     {3}
Wi-Fi                     MIMO Power Save Mode           Auto SMPS                      MIMOPowerSav... {0}
Wi-Fi                     Roaming Aggressiveness         3. Medium                      RoamAggressi... {2}
Wi-Fi                     Preferred Band                 1. No Preference               RoamingPrefe... {0}
Wi-Fi                     Throughput Booster             Disabled                       ThroughputBo... {0}
Wi-Fi                     U-APSD support                 Disabled                       uAPSDSupport    {0}
Wi-Fi                     802.11a/b/g Wireless Mode      6. Dual Band 802.11a/b/g       WirelessMode    {34}
```

Which did not have either of the two addresses I was looking for. As well as this, adding a network address in my network card registry, it did not affect my MAC Address when viewing it, even when restarting my device after. Any suggestions or tips would be very appreciated.

Thanks,
Asian

P.S: I do not want to use any third-party software to assist me in this. I feel like using third party software should be a last resort if it is only for thing you could already do built in with a device (except for Chrome or Opera because Edge is just bad in my opinion). I would rather use the option made for my device instead of installing something extra. I know that NoVirusThanks' MAC Address changer already works, but I would prefer an option built in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use the `getmac -v` command and look for the Wi-Fi label under the "connection name" column

```
 This column
Connection Name Network Adapter Physical Address    Transport Name
=============== =============== =================== ==========================================================
Bluetooth Netwo Bluetooth Devic 08-71-90-B5-40-22   Media disconnected
***Wi-Fi***     Intel(R) Wi-Fi  AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF   \Device\Tcpip_{AAAA1111-BB22-9999-ZZZZ-BLAH2000EEEE}
Ethernet 2      TAP-Windows Ada 11-22-33-44-55-66   Media disconnected
VirtualBox Host VirtualBox Host 0A-00-27-00-00-0E   \Device\Tcpip_{1111AAAA-22BB-0000-CCCC-100YA200FFFF}
```

2. In the same row of the Wi-Fi label, find its transport address (third column). Copy this value

```
                                                     This column
Connection Name Network Adapter Physical Address    Transport Name
=============== =============== =================== ==========================================================
Bluetooth Netwo Bluetooth Devic 08-71-90-B5-40-22   Media disconnected
Wi-Fi           Intel(R) Wi-Fi  AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF   ***THE VALUE SHOWN HERE***
Ethernet 2      TAP-Windows Ada 11-22-33-44-55-66   Media disconnected
VirtualBox Host VirtualBox Host 0A-00-27-00-00-0E   \Device\Tcpip_{1111AAAA-22BB-0000-CCCC-100YA200FFFF}
```

3. Open the registry and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}`.
4. Right-click `{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}` and click "find." Put the value you copied earlier in the box. It will open up a folder and that is your NIC folder in your registry. This will contain your network adapter/network card registry values and information.
   [Screenshot of the right-click menu and the find options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cowTI.png)
   [Find pop-up menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWF3j.png)
5. Right-click the folder that the "find" brought you too and click new --> string value and name it "NetworkAddress" in that exact spelling without the quotes.
6. Double click the "NetworkAddress" value and put in your chosen MAC Address. Make sure it is in the AABBCCDDEEFF format with no spaces or hyphens. Though you can put any 12 digit alphanumeric value here, it sometimes will reject the value so you should put the second digit of the value to be either an a, e, 2, 0, or 6 if it doesn't work
7. Next you must disable the network adapter. You can either do this from control panel, device manager, command prompt or any other way that you may have. I personally use the `netsh interface set interface Wi-Fi disable` command in cmd. This requires an elevated instance of command prompt.
8. For the new changes to take place you pretty much need to restart your adapter by disabling it and then reenabling it any way you wish (again device manager, control panel, command prompt). With me personally I would use an elevated cmd again using `netsh interface set interface Wi-Fi enable`

If you check your MAC address now it should be the same as the NetworkAddress value in your registry. If it isn't, try choosing a different value or disable and enable your network adapter using a different method. Instead of disable and enabling the network adapter you could instead restart your computer. You must remember that the MAC address is built in to the computer and these changes aren't permanent. You are simply using the built in registry function of your network card to spoof a different network address.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for and it worked! Thank you Neko

Comment: "it sometimes will reject the value so you should put the second digit of the value to be either an a, e, 2, 0, or 6 if it doesn't work" - why is that? I need a specific MAC address, it has 4 as a second digit. If I pit 2 it works, but with 4 it does not.

Comment: Note that `Find` should take you to one of the subfolders within `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}`, not a totally different folder. In my case I had to remove the prefix `\Device\Tcpip_` shown under my Transport Name and search for just `{AAAA1111-BB22-9999-ZZZZ-BLAH2000EEEE}`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to open the Registry Editor, you can use a PowerShell cmdlet to change  the Registry Value for you.

1. First, use the `getmac -v` command and search for the name of your Wi-Fi adapter.
2. After that, fill in the name of your adapter and run the following command with elevated privileges:
   `Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "<Wi-Fi adapter name>" -RegistryKeyword "NetworkAddress" -RegistryValue "AABCCDDEEFF"`

Based on [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/set-netadapteradvancedproperty?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-1-set-the-value-of-an-advanced-property-on-the-specified-network-adapter).

Comment: Note you want the *first* column from `getmac -v`, command for the Wi-Fi adapter name, which is *Connection Name*. You do not want the *Transport Name* as listed in Nico's answer.

Answer (score -1):

When use the command *Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "" -RegistryKeyword "NetworkAddress" -RegistryValue "AABCCDDEEFF"*, you may get the error: "*Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty : No matching MSFT_NetAdapterAdvancedPropertySettingData objects found by CIM query for
instances of the ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetAdapterAdvancedPropertySettingData class on the  CIM server: SELECT * FROM
MSFT_NetAdapterAdvancedPropertySettingData  WHERE ((Name LIKE 'Wi-Fi')) AND ((RegistryKeyword = 'NetworkAddress')).
Verify query parameters and retry.*". This happens because the registry value "NetworkAddress" doesn't exist. So I created another PowerShell command, which works for me. This command requires running PowerShell as administrator:

**New-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Wi-Fi" -RegistryKeyword "NetworkAddress" -RegistryValue "AABBCCDDEEFF" -RegistryDataType REG_SZ**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).